If there are multiple resistances that could apply to an instance of damage, how do they stack?
Suppose I have the following stats:

5 Fire Resistance (Charm of Fire Resistance)
3 Resistance to persistent damage (Aeon Stone: Preserving)
2 Resistance to magical attacks from Fiends (Warding Tattoo: Fiend)

If I take 7 persistent fire damage from a fiend's magical attack, how much damage do I take? Do I only use the highest resistance, or do they add up?

The Highest Resistance Applies

If you have more than one type of resistance that would apply to the same instance of damage, use only the highest applicable resistance value, as described in weakness.

